# Angular2 - How to Condition Import, Does More Import Slow Down the Performance?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have this:

```
import {StepOnePage} from '../../pages/step-one/step-one';
import {StepTwoPage} from '../../pages/step-two/step-two';
import {StepThreePage} from '../../pages/step-two/step-one';
import {StepFourPage} from '../../pages/step-two/step-one';
import {StepFivePage} from '../../pages/step-two/step-one';
```

How can I put condition in these import statements?

I tried to import in the constructor, so I can apply the condition:

```
If currentStep is 'Step1' 
    then import StepTwoPage
```

however, it gives me this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'StepOnePage'
```

Or I can import everything as another solution, however, I'm worried about the performance issue that there are more than necessary imports in a page.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to conditionally set imports, it may be a sign that your architecture is problematic. In your example, what do `stepOnePage`, `stepTwoPage` etc... represent? Are they Angular 2 components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imports only have a performance impact during development. After you build a deployable, imports are resolved an everything is packed into a single file (except if you specify to lazy load parts) and there won't be any performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can conditionally `import`. `import` operations are top-level because they have to be parsed and resolved before the code is run. Remember that the whole purpose of `import` is to give the compiler the tools to interpret and execute the rest of the code.

As for performance, `import` will add to the number of network requests and the amount of bandwidth used, so it will have an effect on performance. `import` the stuff you actually need for the current file.